# Finding the limit of a multivariable function using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, limits, polar-coordinates

Doing some review for a Calc III Midterm and I'm confused by the algebra in this Question:

> Calculate the limit or show that it does not exist:
>
> $\lim _{x,y\to
> > \left(0,0\right)}\left(x^2+y^2\right)\ln\left(x^2+y^2\right)$

I have the solution to this problem, but I'm not entirely sure what's happening step by step. It starts off trivially enough; using the rule that $r^2=x^2+y^2$, we get:

$r^2\ln\left(r^2\right)$

But the solution I have then rewrites this as $2r^2\ln\left(r\right)$.

Is this correct? I don't understand how the r in the ln function went down a degree - and how the two was added as a coefficient.

I have a follow up question for the rest of the solution: eventually the solution hinges on using L'hopital, but I don't get how this formula can be rewritten as a fraction (unless you use negative exponents, I guess?).

Finally, I'm not sure how this would prove a limit exists (is this a special property of functions that can be re-expressed with polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Note that:
$$\ln(a^n)=n\ln(a)$$
Where $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

Yes, you should use L'Hopital's rule with negative exponents. Note that:
$$\lim_{r\to 0} 2r^2\ln(r)=2\cdot \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\ln{r}}{\frac{1}{r^2}}$$
Using L'Hopital's rule gives:
$$2\cdot \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{r}}{-\frac{2}{r^3}}=2\cdot \lim_{r \to 0} -\frac{r^2}{2}=\cdots$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me :)

Comment: If I can ask a follow up question, does L'Hopital always provide the limit for a function it be successfully applied to? I.e., if you get a limit via L'Hopital, it always exists?